# sql statement not returning any results

Tags: php, sql, json

Hi I am creating some dummy data in a sql statement and returning the data in a jso n format.  I believe I am connecting to the mysql db ok through odbc.  However the dataset appears to be empty when I run the same query in workbench it returns data ok.

This is how the data is returned to the webpage making the call

```
"[{"coords":{"lat":null,"lng":null},"iconImage":null,"content":null},{"coords":{"lat":null,"lng":null},"iconImage":null,"content":null}]
```

here is my code I have no error messages just empty json.

```
require("../PHP/phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
$connection=odbc_connect($database, $username, $password);



if (!$connection)echo 'Failed to connect';

//Select Test statement 
$query="select 53.745 as lat,-0.338 as lng,'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png' as iconImage, '<h1>Tony G</h1>' as content union all
select 53.745 as lat,-0.310 as lng,'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue.png' as iconImage, '<h1>fred</h1>' as content ";


$result=odbc_exec($connection,$query);

//work through result and create JSON
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($result)){
    $json[] = [
        'coords' => ['lat' => $row['lat'],'lng' => $row['lng']],
        'iconImage' => $row['iconImage'],
        'content' => $row['content'],
    ]; 
} 
echo json_encode($json);
```

I am a little puzzled as to what I am doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: if the while loop doesn't run then `$json` won't be declared and will be "empty" right?

Comment: `print_r($row)`, __what__ do you see?

Comment: Your query seems to be weird, the format is usually, SELECT FIELDNAME, ... FIELDNAME FROM TABLENAME, but you can also log the mysql error using a php function for logging out errors

Comment: if I echo the print_r    "11        



" between the speech marks is the result, the SQL statement is creating false  data to test from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's unclear from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-row.php) where does data go to in `odbc_fetch_row`, it's clear that result (`true` or `false`) of this function is not what you expect. So, you should use another function, which returns array, in this case it is [`odbc_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php):

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
    $json[] = [
        'coords' => ['lat' => $row['lat'],'lng' => $row['lng']],
        'iconImage' => $row['iconImage'],
        'content' => $row['content'],
    ]; 
}
```

Comment: Hi it's still returning empty "                                                          " value